# Powershell Input validation for integer

Tags: powershell

I wanted to write a script that prompts the user to enter a time in minutes for to start shutdown timer. I got it to work but had no input validation. This is what I have.

```
DO{
try{

$numOk= $true
[int] $minutes= Read-Host "Enter the amount in minutes until a shut down (0 to cancel)"
#$minutes= [int]$minutes

}
catch{

#if($minutes -isnot [int]){}
$numOk= $false
Write-Host "Input is not an integer!!!!!"
}

} while ($numOk = $false)


[int] $seconds= $minutes*60

if($seconds -eq 0){
shutdown -a
}
else{
shutdown -s -t $seconds
}
```

I am getting a very weird value when I type a letter in.

```
PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\shut down> .\shutdownTimer.ps1
Enter the amount in minutes until a shut down (0 to cancel): a
Input is not an integer!!!!!
Cannot convert value "555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either 
too large or too small for an Int32."
At C:\Users\USER\Desktop\shut down\shutdownTimer.ps1:25 char:1
+ [int] $seconds= $minutes*60
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger

shutdown : Unable to abort the system shutdown because no shutdown was in progress.(1116)
At C:\Users\USER\Desktop\shut down\shutdownTimer.ps1:29 char:1
+ shutdown -a
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unable to abort...progress.(1116):String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Not quite sure where all those fives come from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code has an error at `while ($numOk = $false)`. In powershell, `=` is the assignment operator. The comparison operators are shell-style: `-eq`, `-ne`, `-gt`, `-gte`, `-lt`, `-lte`, `-like` etc. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6)

You may want to use `[int]::TryParse` to test the input, something like this:

```
$inputValue = 0
do {
    $inputValid = [int]::TryParse((Read-Host 'gimme a number'), [ref]$inputValue)
    if (-not $inputValid) {
        Write-Host "your input was not an integer..."
    }
} while (-not $inputValid)
```

Comment: Simply changing that line to -eq allowed for the loop to properly work. If I enter in a letter now, my Write-Host statement shows up and asks for the user to enter input again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you typecast a variable as `int`, PowerShell automatically checks the input. `a` cannot be assigned to `$minutes` as it cannot be converted to `int`. I'm sure your variable was already assigned in your PowerShell session with `a` as `string`. `'a' * '60'` is 60 times `a` which produces your error. Cleanup your variables and better yet rewrite your code. There is no need for `Read-Host` and all the input validation. PowerShell does all that for you.

```
param(
    # Enter the amount in minutes until a shut down
    [int]$Minutes = 1
)
$Seconds = $Minutes * 60
Start-Sleep -Seconds $Seconds
Stop-Computer
```